# Path as part of pattern matching for method similar to Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

`Directory.GetFiles` has an overload that takes a path and a search pattern:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\path\to\folder", "*.txt");
```

to return files within a specified folder, which match the pattern. Is there a built-in .NET method that takes the path as part of the search pattern?

```
var files1 = Something.GetFiles(@"c:\path\to\folder\*.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like that but I had this need countless times. Fortunately it's easy to write:

```
public string[] SearchFiles(string query)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(query),
        Path.GetFileName(query));
}
```

A less raw version may handle more special cases (if you need it):

```
public string[] SearchFiles(string query)
{
    if (IsDirectory(query))
        return Directory.GetFiles(query, "*.*");

    return Directory.GetFiles(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(query),
        Path.GetFileName(query));
}

private static bool IsDirectory(string path)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces(path))
        return false;

    if (path[path.Length - 1] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        return true;

    if (path[path.Length - 1] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
        return true;

    if (path.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1)
        return false;

    return Directory.Exists(path);
}
```

With this new version (see `IsDirectory()` code) you may use it like this:

```
SearchFiles(@"c:\windows\*.*");
SearchFiles(@"c:\windows\");
SearchFiles(@"c:\windows");
```

Comment: This is sufficient for my needs, but it won't match if there is a wildcard in the folder path, as opposed to a wildcard in only the file name.

Comment: @ZevSpitz absolutely, to match wildcard(s) in path too you have to split search for each chunk in path.